# Viewing a list of locks in Coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion, locking

Is there anyway to see a list of the current locks in Coldfusion (particularly locks on files or directories).

Through a non documented call is fine as this is more for debugging some errors we're getting on our server.

Thanks,

Tom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you might try [FusionDebug](http://www.fusion-reactor.com/fd/), while it is commercial they do have a full featured 20 day trial.  Also the developer edition of Adobe's coldfusion 8 has a server monitor, though its only for your local instance, unless of course you are running the enterprise edition on your production system.

**edit**
While FusionDebug is an excellent eclipse based debugger, i think in your case you want the [FusionReactor](http://www.fusion-reactor.com/fr/) to monitor the system's status.